# Вопрос по библиотеке Telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

Как можно удалить пользователя с помощью библиотеки Telethon на python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот метод, который предоставляет телеграм: https://core.telegram.org/method/account.deleteAccount 
Вот метод в Telethon: https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/account/delete_account.html